# Setting a default value of a parent variable within a datacontact?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a base class

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Key;

    [DataMember]
    public RequestType RequestType;


}
```

There are lots of classes that will inherit this and I'd like them to set their inherited RequestType Enum automatically

```
[DataContract]
public class LoginRequest : BaseRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public void LoginRequest()
    {
        this.RequestType = StationHouseWebServices.RequestType.Login;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Username;

    [DataMember]
    public string Password;
}
```

But since this is a WCF DataContact my service reference will only carry over the DataMembers, not the constructor. Is there a way I can still do this, have a default value for a parent's variable assigned automatically? Something like

```
this.RequestType = StationHouseWebServices.RequestType.Login;
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  I don't see any reason you couldn't set the request type in the constructor.  Yes, the constructor won't carry over but the data will.

Comment: @Tim Unfortunately all of the request objects will be initialized client side, so the constructors won't be called

Comment: @Tim Yea the only worthwhile solution I came up with was to have a virtual property in the base class and to override it with a hardcoded getter in the derived class. The point of this was so I could do a switch statement on the request type (since I can't do a switch on type) but I realize now I can do a switch on the string value of the type.

Comment: @Tim Hey, your comment disappeared

Comment: Sorry - I got to thinking about it and wasn't sure that was the direction to go, so I deleted it.  I think the virtual property is probably the best way to go.

Comment: The only downside I see is from an SOA/Interoperability point of view.  OOP concepts don't cross over to SOA, so I'm not 100% sure how well the concept will cross platform boundaries.  But it couldn't hurt to try and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the constructors won't be called WCF has provided a handy way for you to run any setup code which would normally be executed in the constructor. This is called the `OnDeserializedAttribute`.

```
[OnDeserializedAttribute]
private void RunThisCode(StreamingContext context)
{ 
    ...
}
```

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx